# Highcharts setting the combined line and bar graph maximum width fails

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to set my line graph to have a minimum of 0 and maximum of 100 and even when its a combined line graph the value of the line graph maximum should always remain at 100 even though the other graph y axis increase

So i have

```
      title: {
    text: 'Mombasa Plant Truck Compliance reports'
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: xaxis,
    crosshair: true
  },
  yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
    title: {
      text: 'Passed Inspection',
    },
  },
    { // Primary yAxis
      title: {
        text: 'Failed Inpsection',
      },

    },
    { // Tertiary yAxis
      gridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Percentage Compliance',
      },
      labels: {
        format: '{value} %',
      },
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      opposite: true
    }
  ],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        crop: false,
        overflow: 'none'
      }
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    shared: true
  },
  series: chartdata

}
```

So the above generates
[image]

As you can see the line graph y axis appear to be increasing beyond 100%.
I would like it to be at a maximum of 100

What do i need to adjust as i have already set `max: 100, min: 0,` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to relay only on Highcharts algorithms for finding ticks, you can use `tickPositions` or `tickPositioner`:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositioner

**Demo** for tick positions: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cuutqgys/

Another approach that will work in this particular case is setting `endOnTick` to false: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dxq4y822/